# Jenkins with GIT plugin - checkout specific tag and also limited to a specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, deployment

I have managed to configure a jenkins task to checkout a specific GIT tag for further deployment to a remote server following this great blog post http://erics-notes.blogspot.be/2013/05/jenkins-build-latest-git-tag.html

In short I need to define refspec and branch properties to the following values in jenkins jobs SCM configuration:

```
Refspec: +refs/tags/live/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/live/*
Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): */tags/live/*
```

But now, I imagine that anybody of our developers could create a tag with a name elligible for deployment (live/...). The GIT plugin for jenkins traverses all available branches looking for matching tag names.

How can I ensure in a jenkins job (configured as described in the blog post above), that a tag is checked out only if the underlying commit is on a specific branch, e.g. our protected "master" branch?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive search for answers to the question above I have a feeling, that it is not possible to restrict the deployment to tags pointing to commits on a specific branch. I found somewhere an answer to similar question (which I can not find again today) stating, that "GIT is not designed that way". Tags live in a global namespace not bound to any branch.
So the only solution could be e.g. restrict the tagging possibility for certain users, but that is a different story and I do not want to follow that path any further.

Feel free to confirm that some day please :-)

At the beginnining I had the idea of deploying HEAD of the "master" branch to STAGE and a specific tag (from master branch) to LIVE.
Now I will just introduce another branch to deploy to STAGE from.

Comment: Tags along with branch name is always a better option to control the dev and prod deployments. If some one is having access to master and allowed to create tags, they should be able to do it any way. Hence better to have two dedicated pipelines with platform specific tags like dev-* and prod-* of their respective branches.